# ¿Cómo puedo sustituir según una máscara booleana los valores true por un número?

Tags: python, numpy

Estoy tratando de sustituir los múltiplos de 3 de una matriz por -1 sin usar bucles, es decir, mediante una máscara booleana.

La matriz es la siguiente:

```
C = np.arange(92,292,2).reshape((10,10))
```

y la máscara booleana:

```
mascara = ((A%3) == 0)
```

No consigo averiguar cómo sustituir los valores de la
matriz A que toman el valor true en la máscara por -1.

Estoy usando jupyter, sage math, en un archivo de python 3 y el módulo numpy.

Answer (score 1):

Como rápido, puedes usar esto !!!

```py
c = np.arange(92,292,2).reshape((10,10))

# Forma 1
new_c = np.where(c % 3 == 0, -1, c)
print (c, new_c)

# Forma 2, usando máscara
mascara = ((c%3) == 0)
c[mascara] = -1

print (c)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias !!! ^^